# Health cloud : Adding Visual Force Page to Patient Card Navigation Menu and Patient Subtabs Data not Pulling

Tags: salesforce-id, health-cloud

### Patient Card Navigation Menu and Patient Sub-tabs:

I have Created one Visulaforce page and I want to render that visulaforce page after clicking on Patient Card Navigation Menu. For that I have addded a new Record into the Custom Setting i.e. "Card View Dropdown" follow the same process as per the below link -

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_card_view_menu.html

- But still I am facing issue related to "Data Pulling". Could you please look into this issue and Let me Know some feedback..

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your custom setting has below fields populated for redirecting:

1. URL : /apex/VFPageName
2. Page Type   : VFpage